# enum values containing spaces

Tags: java, enums

```
enum Commands
{
    ADDPLAYER, REMOVEPLAYER, EDITPLAYER, RESETSTATS,
    DISPLAYPLAYER, RANKINGS, STARTGAME, EXIT
};
```

So I have the following commands for a game. I am now required to introduce the commands "rankings asc" and "rankings desc", ie specifying rankings in ascending or descending order rather than just rankings. I'm unsure how to do this. I tried to add "RANKINGS ASC" /DESC to the enum Commands list but that doesn't work due to the space. The command needs to have a space in between the two terms when called in the program, called exactly as "rankings asc". The other commands will be used normally (used by cases). Any ideas? Can the rankings command have arguments?

Comment: I cannot tell what you are asking. Something is supposed to be in ascending or descending order; is it the commands, or the players, or something else? You can use arguments in the constructors of `enum` types, but I can't tell if it will help because I can't tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you use enums you should go with RANKINGS_ASC an RANKINGS_DESC

Comment: You seem to be confusing the internal name of the enum value (used within your program) with the value seen by the user.  It is easy to attach external string values to internal enum constants, and this is documented in many places.

Comment: Thanks guys I understand it now. Sorry for my confusing question. I'm new to java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to separate words in constant names is not whitespace :  that is not valid for identifiers but underscore : `_` , that is :

```
RANKINGS_ASC, RANKINGS_DESC
```

This is right for enum values like for `final static` field constants names.

> The command needs to have a space in between the two terms when called
>   in the program, called exactly as "rankings asc".

The enum values are compile type constant values.  These represent the logic name of the enum, these are not designed to represent exact textual values entered by the clients of the application. In some cases, they may but they may not in some other cases and that is acceptable.
To achieve your requirement you could define an enum with a parameter constructor where the parameter represents the textual commands entered by the client.
But now if the single mapping requirement is for these 2 cases, just replace the whitespace by an underscore and use `Enum.valueOf(String)` to get the enum such as :

```
Command command = Commands.valueOf(clientCommand.replace(" ", "_"))
```

Note that you can add a param for an emum constructor as illustrated by Babyburger (miam) but it makes sense only if the param makes sense for every enum values because you want to manipulate it uniformly. If that is not the case here, you should probably not use this way.

Comment: @Downvoter please could you explain how my answer could be improved ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Lots of people downvoting here which I think is my fault, sorry about that

Comment: You are welcome. I agree about downvoting, that is rather annoying.  No, it is not your fault at all. Your question is correct but the way which some downvotes for unclear reason is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have spaces in your enum names.  But you can add arguments to enums:

```
enum Commands
{
    ADDPLAYER("addplayer"), REMOVEPLAYER("removeplayer"), RANKINGS_ASC("rankings asc"), RANKINGS_DESC("rankings desc")

    private String name;

    Commands(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
};
```